# How to synchronously detect if user has denied permission to access geolocation data?

Tags: javascript, w3c-geolocation

Referring to: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#permission_denied_error

How to detect synchronously (and without prompting dialog asking to accept the permission) whether user has previously declined access to the geolocation data?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform the check synchronously. I would suggest storing a value to localStorage if they have previously denied access:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function () { 
  // success
  localStorage.setItem('userDeniedGeo', false);
}, function (err) { 
  // if permission denied
  if (err.code === 1) {
    localStorage.setItem('userDeniedGeo', true);
  }
});
```

From then on you can access localStorage for the answer instead of using the `navigator`, which will by synchronous

```
localStorage.getItem('userDeniedGeo');
```

Comment: What about asynchronous method? My problem with `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` is that it automatically triggers the permission dialog.

Comment: Regarding your solution using `localStorage`, I would advise against, because user can grant the permission at any time and your script will not be aware of this change.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas unfortunately there's no way to do what you want exactly.